# OAuth 2 refresh token invalid_grant

Tags: asp.net, ajax, oauth, access-token

Following Taiseer Joudeh excellent article
Enable OAuth Refresh Tokens in AngularJS App using ASP .NET Web API 2, and Owin (http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) currently I am creating a Token based authentication with refresh token option.

My Startup class code is as follows:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {

                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
    }
```

My SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider class code is as follows:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {

            string clientId = string.Empty;
            string clientSecret = string.Empty;
            Client client = null;

            if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
            {
                context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
            }

            if (context.ClientId == null)
            {
                //Remove the comments from the below line context.SetError, and invalidate context 
                //if you want to force sending clientId/secrects once obtain access tokens. 
                context.Validated();
                //context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "ClientId should be sent.");
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                client = _repo.FindClient(context.ClientId);
            }

            if (client == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_clientId", string.Format("Client '{0}' is not registered in the system.", context.ClientId));
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            if (client.ApplicationType == Models.ApplicationTypes.NativeConfidential)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client secret should be sent.");
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (client.Secret != Helper.GetHash(clientSecret))
                    {
                        context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client secret is invalid.");
                        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!client.Active)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client is inactive.");
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin", client.AllowedOrigin);
            context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime", client.RefreshTokenLifeTime.ToString());

            context.Validated();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");

            if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";

            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });
            //var id = "";
            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
                //Here set User.Identity.Id = RavenUserId, So rest of the user will be able to get it
                //id = (user == null ? "0" : user.RavenUserId.ToString());
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            //So when we will call User.Identity.Id we will be able to get Raven User Id
           // identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, id));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { 
                        "as:client_id", (context.ClientId == null) ? string.Empty : context.ClientId
                    },
                    { 
                        "userName", context.UserName
                    }
                });

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
            context.Validated(ticket);

        }

        public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
        {
            var originalClient = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
            var currentClient = context.ClientId;

            if (originalClient != currentClient)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Refresh token is issued to a different clientId.");
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            // Change auth ticket for refresh token requests
            var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);

            var newClaim = newIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "newClaim").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newClaim != null)
            {
                newIdentity.RemoveClaim(newClaim);
            }
            newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "newValue"));

            var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
            context.Validated(newTicket);

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }


        public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

My SimpleRefreshTokenProvider class code is as follows:

```
public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
    {

        public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            var clientid = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientid))
            {
                return;
            }

            var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

            using (var _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime");

                var token = new RefreshToken()
                {
                    Id = Helper.GetHash(refreshTokenId),
                    ClientId = clientid,
                    Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
                    IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(refreshTokenLifeTime))
                };

                context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedUtc;
                context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = token.ExpiresUtc;

                token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();

                var result = await _repo.AddRefreshToken(token);

                if (result)
                {
                    context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
                }

            }
        }

        public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {

            var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

            string hashedTokenId = Helper.GetHash(context.Token);

            using (var _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var refreshToken = await _repo.FindRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);

                if (refreshToken != null)
                {
                    //Get protectedTicket from refreshToken class
                    context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
                    var result = await _repo.RemoveRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The AuthRepository class code is as follows:

```
public class AuthRepository : IDisposable
    {
        private AuthContext _ctx;

        private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public AuthRepository()
        {
            _ctx = new AuthContext();
            _userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(_ctx));
        }

        public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserModel userModel)
        {
            IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = userModel.UserName
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);

            return result;
        }

        public async Task<IdentityUser> FindUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

            return user;
        }


        public Client FindClient(string clientId)
        {
            var client = _ctx.Clients.Find(clientId);
            //var clients = _ctx.Clients;
            //var client = _ctx.Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id==clientId);
            return client;
        }

        public async Task<bool> AddRefreshToken(RefreshToken token)
        {

            var existingToken = _ctx.RefreshTokens.Where(r => r.Subject == token.Subject && r.ClientId == token.ClientId).SingleOrDefault();

            if (existingToken != null)
            {
                var result = await RemoveRefreshToken(existingToken);
            }

            _ctx.RefreshTokens.Add(token);

            return await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }

        public async Task<bool> RemoveRefreshToken(string refreshTokenId)
        {
            var refreshToken = await _ctx.RefreshTokens.FindAsync(refreshTokenId);

            if (refreshToken != null)
            {
                _ctx.RefreshTokens.Remove(refreshToken);
                return await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public async Task<bool> RemoveRefreshToken(RefreshToken refreshToken)
        {
            _ctx.RefreshTokens.Remove(refreshToken);
            return await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }

        public async Task<RefreshToken> FindRefreshToken(string refreshTokenId)
        {
            var refreshToken = await _ctx.RefreshTokens.FindAsync(refreshTokenId);

            return refreshToken;
        }

        public List<RefreshToken> GetAllRefreshTokens()
        {
            return _ctx.RefreshTokens.ToList();
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            _ctx.Dispose();
            _userManager.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

And the ajax code is:

```
$("#refresh").click(function () {
                var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
                var refresh = sessionStorage.getItem('isRefreshToken');
                var refreshToken = sessionStorage.getItem('refreshToken');

                if (refresh) {
                    var refreshdata = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + refreshToken + "&client_id=TokenBasedAuthentication";
                    console.log(refreshdata);

                    sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, '');
                    sessionStorage.setItem(isRefreshToken, '');
                    sessionStorage.setItem(refreshToken, '');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/token',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: refreshdata,
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                        success: function (data) {

                            sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
                            sessionStorage.setItem(isRefreshToken, true);
                            sessionStorage.setItem(refreshToken, data.refresh_token);

                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
                        }

                    });
                }

            });
```

Finally when I click on Refresh it returns me following error
**error: "invalid_grant"**

Last two days I tried to figure out but failed.

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue. Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: I'm stuck as well and even implemented JwtSecurityTokenHandler to make sure it passes all the checks, and it does. But I still get the invalid_grant. How to debug?

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem where I was always receiving a invalid_grant error even though I knew the refresh_token was valid.  Granted there are a lot of reasons why there might be a invalid_grant error, but after debugging through the code I discovered that my issue was in the CreateAsync method. The refreshTokenLifetime variable was null.  Thus, when the RefreshToken is created, the ExpiresUtc value is already expired, causing the invalid_grant error.  To resolve this I verified that I had a valid value for the refreshTokenLifetime variable.

```
    var refreshTokenLifetime = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:RefreshTokenLifetime") ?? "60";
```

Comment: I think there could be any number of problems that lead to the infuriatingly vague "invalid_grant" catch-all error, but I had this problem and it turned out that your answer here was right on the money!!  In my case I had a case difference between the setting of the `..Lifetime` in the dictionary and retrieving the `LifeTime` !!  As I was following the tutorial I was thinking "*not using constants for these keys is asking for trouble*" ... and lo and behold !!  :)   My implementation is now working perfectly !!  Thank you !!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I also run into the "invalid_grant" error and your hint solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 
Remove this line of code `newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "newValue"));` from your `GrantRefreshToken` function of `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider` class. As this line is of no use.
It is duplicating the claim when you request for new refresh token. So it is opposing you.

Comment: how to debug/log so we can get actual cause instead of guessing?

Answer (score 0):

In **ReceiveAsync** method in **SimpleRefreshTokenProvider** class:

```
var refreshToken = await _repo.FindRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
```

inspect **refreshToken** object to make sure all of its attributes have valid values.

In my case **ProtectedTicket** property has invalid value (Date value instead of string) and it causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your code is passing clientid wile making call for refresh token, but I don't see the client secret. It is also needed. See below screenshot from Postman.

[image]